# Unpacking vs for loop to print elements in list

Tags: python

I was solving some practice questions using Python, and in one of the questions, I had to iterate over a list of numbers and print each element on a separate line.

In my first attempt, I tried to do:

```py
nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ...with more numbers]

for num in nums:
  print(num)
```

This allowed me to pass the test cases for the question, but I got curious to see how other people approached the question and so checked out some of their solutions.

I noticed that someone was using the unpacking operator to achieve the same thing as my for loop above, like so:

```py
print(*nums, sep='\n')
```

When I executed the code above that uses the unpacking operator, I noticed that the execution time for the script increased by ~50%.

This might have been due to other factors of course, but is there a chance that the unpacking of my list had an impact on the performance?

And if it did, why would it?

Comment: If you have no other condition to do. To print a list simply you can pass `print(nums)`

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code with a list of `1,000,000` elements and I got similar results for both the loop and the unpacking print, 5.1sec, and 5sec respectively. If the exercises were not run on your pc, the machine that checks for correctness might have been busy in the unpacking run.

Comment: @MikeXydas ah I see, that makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tested both codes with Python 3.9.1 on macOS (version 10.15.7, 2.5 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5) and could find any significant difference in performance.

First of all, I checked CPython bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>>
>>> code1 = """\
... nums = list(range(1000))
...
... for num in nums:
...     print(num)
... """
>>> code2 = """\
... nums = list(range(1000))
... print(*nums, sep='\\n')
... """
>>>
>>> dis.dis(code1)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (nums)

  2          12 LOAD_NAME                2 (nums)
             14 GET_ITER
        >>   16 FOR_ITER                12 (to 30)
             18 STORE_NAME               3 (num)

  3          20 LOAD_NAME                4 (print)
             22 LOAD_NAME                3 (num)
             24 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             26 POP_TOP
             28 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           16
        >>   30 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
             32 RETURN_VALUE
>>> dis.dis(code2)
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (list)
              2 LOAD_NAME                1 (range)
              4 LOAD_CONST               0 (1000)
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              8 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             10 STORE_NAME               2 (nums)

  2          12 LOAD_NAME                3 (print)
             14 LOAD_NAME                2 (nums)
             16 LOAD_CONST               1 ('sep')
             18 LOAD_CONST               2 ('\n')
             20 BUILD_MAP                1
             22 CALL_FUNCTION_EX         1
             24 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               3 (None)
             28 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can see for the second code, the list wasn't being unpacked (`LOAD_NAME print, LOADNAME num` vs `LOAD_NAME print, LOADNAME nums`).

Also, I even `timeit` it:

```
from timeit import timeit

def f1():
    nums = list(range(1000))

    for num in nums:
        print(num)

def f2():
    nums = list(range(1000))
    print(*nums, sep='\n')

print(timeit(f1, number=20000))
print(timeit(f2, number=20000))
```

and got very similar results (397.45 vs 399.58 seconds).